# Yii CListView pager stretches to much

Tags: yii

I used Yii CListView widget to paginate thru results.

I have a container div with position:relative and float:left.

I have 2 div's, each with float:left inside the container.

The problem is that if I have to many pages with results, the seccond div falls under the first div.

I need them both, on the same line, as ishown in image 2.

Does yii's clistview have a property that sets the maximum number of pages to be echoed in the pager?

I don't need the clistview to print the pages from 60 to 69; from 60 to 65 is enought, so a limit of 6 should be enought.

Any ideas?

[image: image here]

[image: image here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set [`maxButtonCount`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CLinkPager#maxButtonCount-detail) attribute of [`CLinkPager`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CLinkPager) to 5. The `CLinkPager` attributes can be specified through [`pager`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CBaseListView#pager-detail) attribute of [`CListView`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CListView)

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'itemView'=>'_item_view',  
    'pager'=>array(
         'class'=>'CLinkPager',
         // This attribute species how many buttons are displayed
         'maxButtonCount'=>5
    ),
   .....,
   .....
));
```

Answer (score 0):

you could just pass it in the pager property and it'd override the default value :`'pager' => array(
               'maxButtonCount' => 5
    ),`

Comment: pagesize is used to limit the articles per page; i need to limit the page numbers printed by the widget